# How to use Google Analytcis Event Tracking to track clicks on <div> element

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm new to GA and programming in general, but event tracking has been pretty straightforward until I encountered this div for a find my location button.

This is what I've tried:

`<div id="locateButton" onclick="ga('send','event','Map Button','click','Find My Location')"></div>`

I also tried using `onmouseover` but no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just putting another `div` around it and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not a fan of doing stuff like that "inline" just due to maintenance nightmares, there should be nothing wrong with that. Are you receiving any error messages in the console? Are you loading your Google Analytics tracking code in the `head` ? As long as your GA code is loaded before that div is on the page, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No error messages in the console. Just working in one file "(index.html). GA code is in the head, and 20+ other inline `onclick` events are being tracked. :-/.